# Prompt Login for Domain Users to Access Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-for-education

I've created a few forms with Google Apps Script and selected the option "share only with [my domain]."  All goes well, but if a user is already logged into a non-[my domain] Google account, they receive the message "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."  With no prompt to log in.

Is there any way to avoid this and prompt/nudge a user to log into [my domain]?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. This is not particular to Apps Script or Google Apps in general either.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with App Script.

However, if the user is not granted access to the form they will see a page telling them this is the case and allowing then to sign in with a different account. See screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhQe0.png